# Text not aligning vertically at the center of select dropdown in material UI core

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, material-ui

Please see the image. The text is not aligning at the center of the text box like the other text box fields in the form

[Drop down not at the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8OnA.png)

Here is my code

```
                          <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small">
        <InputLabel
          htmlFor="Implementation Status"
          style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        >
          Implementation Status
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="Implementation Status"
          name="name"
          onChange={handleChange("Status")}
          defaultValue={values.Status}
          variant="outlined"
          inputProps={{
            id: "Implementation Status",
            name: "age"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="Implemented">Implemented</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Implementation in Progress">
            Implementation in Progress
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Not Implemented">Not Implemented</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

      <br />
      <br />
```

Comment: you have added any external css for width & height ?

Comment: no I have not used any external css

Comment: can you please provide codesandbox demo  so, can check .

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-kare-fwe2c?file=/src/App.js     Here is the link

Comment: i didn't see your code in sandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-tree-fh1sx?file=/src/App.js   Here is the link again, may be I did not save it last time. I am newly using sandbox

Comment: Oh I checked its not showing the changes I made

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-tree-fh1sx?file=/src/App.js:0-1050   Here is the link the sandbox was not copying the link properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small">
        <InputLabel id="Implementation-Status" style={{ marginLeft: 10,top:"50%",transform:"translate(0,-50%" }}>
          Implementation Status
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="Implementation-Status"
          name="name"
          variant="outlined"
          inputProps={{
            id: "Implementation Status",
            name: "age"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="Implemented">Implemented</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Implementation in Progress">
            Implementation in Progress
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Not Implemented">Not Implemented</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @sandeep pradhan if this ans to your que than please upvote this que.